# Generate text_field for attribute in form_for after choosing a specific selection in select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I have a form_for an instrument object that lets you choose the type of instrument from a drop-down menu. However, I would like the user to be able to enter their own type if they do not see an adequate type in the drop-down.

There is another question similar to this one on here, that suggests using a JavaScript event handler and a hidden text field, but it does not seem to work. I am open to a JS solution, but I do not know JavaScript so I would need some guidance.

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @instrument do |f| %>
<%= f.label :type %><br>
<%= f.select :type, Instrument.instrument_list, :include_blank => true %><br />
<%= f.label :family %><br>
<%= f.select :family, ['Woodwind', 'Brass', 'String', 'Percussion', 'Other'] %><br>
<%= f.label :range %><br>
<%= f.select :range, ['Soprano', 'Alto', 'Tenor', 'Baritone', 'Bass', 'N/A'] %><br>
<%= f.submit @instrument.new_record? ? "Add Instrument" : "Update Instrument" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I cause a text field to appear once the user chooses "other" or "add your own"?

Comment: Ah Type is not an allowed field in Ruby....I changed it to name

Comment: `type` has no special significance in Ruby. But it does as a column name in ActiveRecord as its used for Single Table Inheritance.